# JQuery share functionality between autocompletes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Example JQuery autocomplete code.  I wamt one function that can be called by two seperate autocomplete instatiations which allows me share the same functionality without rewriting 
the code.

```
$("tags1").autocomplete(
{
               source: availableTags
});
```

To make sure this is clear. I dont want to repeat the code. So when I use another autocomplete elsewhere I want to reference the code contained inside autocomplete and not repeat the code (I just repeated myself)

Comment: Does your auto complete data not depend on what is typed into the textbox? Is the autocomplete data being sent form a server?

Comment: @Dve yes, but I have two that are exactly the same and dont want to repeat the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a manual ajax get request to get the data, store it in a variable and then just that variable for both autocompletes.

```
var cache = {},
    requestData = function(request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        if(term in cache) {
            response(cache[term]);
            return;
        }

        $.getJSON("search.php", request, function(data, status, xhr) {
            cache[term] = data;
            response(data);
        });
    };

$("#birds").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: requestData
});

$("#moreBirds").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: requestData
});
```

source: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/remote-with-cache.html

But you should really send cache headers from the server telling the client to cache the result of the request. Then when the second autocomplete makes the same request the browser wont have to hit the server again.

This is a great article on the subject: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers

Comment: My question might not be clear. What I am trying to do is have one function that can be called by two seperate autocomplete instatiations which allows me share the same functionality without rewriting the code.

Comment: @Jonathan You can reuse the source function - answer updated.

Comment: Indeed I see. Is there a way to abstract all properties?

Comment: Your way might be the best way of doing it because you can compose a solution.

Comment: The parameter you pass to autocomplete() just needs to be a javascript object, so you can compose it however you want. You could create: var opts = { minLength: 2, source: function (req, resp) { //... } };

Comment: perfect you helped me out a great deal! I added your comments to the answer!